# CSS3 Columns - Extra width after second element added

Tags: html, css, markup

I have an element that has CSS3 columns applied to it. The element (`div.parent`) has a `min-width` and a `max-width`. Child elements (`article.space`) will be appended to the parent element, filling the left column and then filling the right column.

Here's the markup with one child element:

```
<div class="parent" style="height: 888px;">
    <article class="space">
        <header>
            <h3>Header3</h3>
            <h4>Header4</h4>
            <h5>Header5</h5>
        </header>
        <section>
            <img src="" alt="img">
            <p>3:06</p>
        </section>
    </article>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
    -webkit-column-width: 190px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
    min-width: 190px;
    max-width: 410px;
}

.space {
     width: 190px;
     height: 50px;
     display: inline-block;
}
```

So basically, the div's are rectangle shaped, and they need to fill the first column and then the second column, and then if I set `.parent`'s `max-width` to a greater number, the third column, etc.

It all works except for one thing. If I append more than 2 `article.space`, `.parent` expands to it's `max-width`. When there is only one `article.space`, `.parent`'s width is fine, but if there are two or more it auto expands it to the `max-width` set.

Here's some pictures: (I apologize for all the white boxes, I cannot share what this is for)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It will be easier to help you with that issue if we will be able to see the live example (you can use jsfiddle for that).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. What's the problem?
http://jsfiddle.net/zMGyp/